# gRPC doesn't seem to generate client side code needed for accessing service

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I am exploring gRPC by downloading and following the PortfoliosSample from [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers).
The sample code are all working fine. When I tried to create my own simple service and client by following the sample, however, I noticed that the generated code on the client side doesn't include the class and functions needed for accessing the service.
In the PortfoliosSample, the client side code generated based on the portfolios.proto includes and class named PortfoliosClinet (in PortfoliosGrpc.cs)

```
public partial class PortfoliosClient : grpc::ClientBase<PortfoliosClient>
```

Various functions (such as Get, in the class) are available for client side program to use for invoking the service.

In my generated code, BrokerGrpc.cs, there is no "GroupClient" class or anything similar in it. As a result, my client side code cannot use the generated code to access the service. What am I missing?

Here is the TSAPIBroker.proto file defined on the server

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos";

package TSAPIBroker;

message Group {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}

message Groups {
    repeated Group group = 1;
}

message GetRequest {
    int32 groupId = 1;
}

message GetResponse {
    Group group = 1;
}
service GroupService 
{
    rpc Get(GetRequest) returns (GetResponse);
}
```

And here is the generated TSAPIBrokerGrpc.cs

```
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
//     source: TSAPIBroker.proto
// </auto-generated>
#pragma warning disable 0414, 1591
#region Designer generated code

using grpc = global::Grpc.Core;

namespace Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos {
  public static partial class GroupService
  {
    static readonly string __ServiceName = "TSAPIBroker.GroupService";

    static readonly grpc::Marshaller<global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetRequest> __Marshaller_TSAPIBroker_GetRequest = grpc::Marshallers.Create((arg) => global::Google.Protobuf.MessageExtensions.ToByteArray(arg), global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetRequest.Parser.ParseFrom);
    static readonly grpc::Marshaller<global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetResponse> __Marshaller_TSAPIBroker_GetResponse = grpc::Marshallers.Create((arg) => global::Google.Protobuf.MessageExtensions.ToByteArray(arg), global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetResponse.Parser.ParseFrom);

    static readonly grpc::Method<global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetRequest, global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetResponse> __Method_Get = new grpc::Method<global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetRequest, global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetResponse>(
        grpc::MethodType.Unary,
        __ServiceName,
        "Get",
        __Marshaller_TSAPIBroker_GetRequest,
        __Marshaller_TSAPIBroker_GetResponse);

    /// <summary>Service descriptor</summary>
    public static global::Google.Protobuf.Reflection.ServiceDescriptor Descriptor
    {
      get { return global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.TSAPIBrokerReflection.Descriptor.Services[0]; }
    }

    /// <summary>Base class for server-side implementations of GroupService</summary>
    [grpc::BindServiceMethod(typeof(GroupService), "BindService")]
    public abstract partial class GroupServiceBase
    {
      public virtual global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task<global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetResponse> Get(global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetRequest request, grpc::ServerCallContext context)
      {
        throw new grpc::RpcException(new grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode.Unimplemented, ""));
      }

    }

    /// <summary>Creates service definition that can be registered with a server</summary>
    /// <param name="serviceImpl">An object implementing the server-side handling logic.</param>
    public static grpc::ServerServiceDefinition BindService(GroupServiceBase serviceImpl)
    {
      return grpc::ServerServiceDefinition.CreateBuilder()
          .AddMethod(__Method_Get, serviceImpl.Get).Build();
    }

    /// <summary>Register service method with a service binder with or without implementation. Useful when customizing the  service binding logic.
    /// Note: this method is part of an experimental API that can change or be removed without any prior notice.</summary>
    /// <param name="serviceBinder">Service methods will be bound by calling <c>AddMethod</c> on this object.</param>
    /// <param name="serviceImpl">An object implementing the server-side handling logic.</param>
    public static void BindService(grpc::ServiceBinderBase serviceBinder, GroupServiceBase serviceImpl)
    {
      serviceBinder.AddMethod(__Method_Get, serviceImpl == null ? null : new grpc::UnaryServerMethod<global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetRequest, global::Test.API.TSAPIBroker.Protos.GetResponse>(serviceImpl.Get));
    }

  }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the container image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0`, I'm able to use your proto to generate both files:

- `TSAPIBroker.cs`
- `TSAPIBrokerGrpc.cs`

Repro:

```sh
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Grpc --version 2.33.1
dotnet add package Grpc.Tools --version 2.33.1
dotnet add package Google.Api.CommonProtos --version 2.2.0
```

Reference your proto from ther project file and then build.

My generated `*Grpc.cs` contains `GroupServiceClient`class.

> **NOTE** the message `Groups` is defined but not used.

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin for the inputs! I updated my Grpc packages from 2.23.2 to 2.33.1 using VS.Net 2019's NuGet management tool and it didn't fix my issue. Then I noticed that my client side project file contains a line: <Protobuf Include="..\TestAPIBroker\Protos\TestAPIBroker.proto" GrpcServices="Server">. After changing the "Server" to "Client" and recompile, I have the client functions generated in the *Grpc.cs file. Still not clear why I have to manually change the GrpcServices value but I am ok now. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!